# CUDA 5.5 encoding sample

Tags: cuda, nvidia

When I run sample encoding project it creates plush_480p_60fr.264 file but this created file is corrupted. What can the reason of this be?

Comment: How do you know it's corrupted?  Did you make any changes to anything in the project?  Is this on linux or windows?

Comment: I cant open it with vlc player, I use windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a problem with vlc player.  I downloaded vlc 2.08 and I also could not play the file.
However, on the same computer (windows7) I have cyberlink mediashow 5 and it recognized and could play the file.

[image: cyberlink mediashow 5]

When I changed the filename from plush_480p_60fr.264 to plush_480p_60fr.avi, windows media player could also play the file.

I don't think windows media player will recognize the file normally, but with the additional codecs installed by cyberlink mediashow 5, I believe windows media player could also recognize and play the file.

You'll need to try other media players besides vlc.
You should also verify that when you run cudaEncode.exe, there are no errors and the encoding process ends with:

> cudaEncode.exe encoded OK, return value = 0

and that you end up with a file size of around 900KBytes (it's a short video clip)

Comment: My problem was to assume that .264 file is a muxed, playable video. I used avc2avi to convert it and now i see that there is no problem with the file. Thanks a lot.